# How to work on a project using Windows 10 using an Ubuntu server set on a VM? (for an almost total linux env feel)

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

- I have a Windows 10 desktop computer
- I have installed Ubuntu server, docker & git.
- I set up nginx (via docker) and pulled a project (via git)

Hurray! I have everything working on the VM side.

Is is possible, somehow, to edit my project files on the Windows side, while auto-syncing the files on the VM? (as if it's a total Ubuntu server environment)

- I do not want to work with Windows 10 built in Ubuntu server (I prefer settling for an Ubuntu Desktop VM instead!)
- I want to avoid any problems with GIT push/pulls permission and Unix file types issues (I had something like this at work long time ago)

What is the ideal solution for this kind of case? 
Is it even possible? How?

Comment: You can research `docker-machine` or `sshfs`. There's also Docker for Windows which transparently runs a Docker VM behind the scenes.

Comment: I do not want to install the docker for windows, or anything on the windows side, except the code editor

Comment: Well, you could give shared folders a try, but the performance will be terrible and you'll have permission issues. Or you can run VS Code in client-server mode, if that's what you're using. Otherwise I doubt you'll get this setup working without installing anything else.

Comment: @gronostaj thank you